# Что не так с выводом массива?

Tags: java

Имеется код. Эклипс ошибок не выдаёт. Однако при компиляции выводится абракадабра, но в дебаггере (внутри) все ок. Что не так? Заранее благодарю!

```
package arrays;

    //Returning an Array from a Method

    public class TestArrays4 {
    public static int[] reverse(int[] list) {
           int[] result = new int[list.length];

           for (int i = 0, j = result.length - 1; i < list.length; i++, j--){
              result[j] = list[i];
           }
           return result;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] c = reverse(a);

        System.out.println("hi " + c);
    }
}
```

в консоли

```
hi [I@1db9742
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что Вы неправильно выводите содержимое массива на консоль.

В строке:

```
System.out.println("hi " + c);
```

происходит неявный вызов метода `toString()` класса `Object`, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Как видно, он возвращает имя класса и шестнадцатеричное представление хэшкода объекта. Собственно, это Вы и получаете.

Вывести содержимое массива можно, например, так:

```
for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(c[i]);
}
```

или так:

```
for (int i : c) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

или так (Java 8):

```
Arrays.stream(c).forEach(System.out::println);
```

или можно воспользоваться методом `toString(...)` класса `Arrays`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```